# Distinguish tab versus tap on UITextField entry?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is there any way to determine whether a user tabbed into a `UITextField` via an external keyboard, or tapped on the textfield?  I would like to have two different cases for `UITextFieldShouldBeginEditing`, depending on the manner in which a user reached the field.

I have tried the addTarget method as well as the `addGestureRecognizer` method, but as of iOS7, neither seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do it after iOS 6. A workaround is explained in this link to detect a text field tab.

http://weaklyreferenced.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/responding-to-the-tab-and-shift-tab-keys-on-ios-5-ios-6-with-an-external-keyboard/

No delegate method is called when a UITextField is tabbed, that means the delegate method will be called only when it is tapped. So, that would distinguish the two operations.